# Why does EventInfo.EventHandlerType return a nullable Type value?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

The `EventHandlerType` property of the `System.Reflection.EventInfo` class is declared as returning a nullable `Type?`:

> [EventInfo.EventHandlerType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.eventinfo.eventhandlertype?view=net-8.0)
>
> ```cs
> public virtual Type? EventHandlerType { get; }
> ```

Surely any event must have a type -- so why is the return value nullable?

If I inspect the disassembly of an implementation, I think I see that it cannot return null:

```cs
namespace System.Reflection.TypeLoading
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for all EventInfo objects created by a MetadataLoadContext.
    /// </summary>
    internal abstract partial class RoEvent : LeveledEventInfo
    {

        public sealed override Type EventHandlerType => _lazyEventType ?? (_lazyEventType = ComputeEventHandlerType());
        protected abstract Type ComputeEventHandlerType();
        private volatile Type? _lazyEventType;
```

And it's unlike similar properties, like `FieldInfo.FieldType` and `MethodInfo.ReturnType`, which return `Type` not `Type?`.

Comment: You're not looking at the actual source in the `EventInfo` class, [here it is](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/EventInfo.cs,43). As you can see, it can return null in a very specific case. I don't know how that can happen in practice, however.

Comment: Ok thank you! Using C#, Visual Studio won't let me define an event that isn't a delegate type, but maybe the IL is more permissive than that. Thank you too for the link to the source code. Also I note that the GetAddMethod itoo s declared as returning a nullable MemberInfo but is assumed not to. And if you'd repost your comment as an answer, then I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at [the source for `EventInfo.EventHandlerType`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/EventInfo.cs,43):

```
public virtual Type? EventHandlerType
{
    get
    {
        MethodInfo m = GetAddMethod(true)!;
        ReadOnlySpan<ParameterInfo> p = m.GetParametersAsSpan();
        Type del = typeof(Delegate);
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            Type c = p[i].ParameterType;
            if (c.IsSubclassOf(del))
                return c;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The way it works is by getting the event's `add` method, enumerating its parameters, and returning the first one that inherits from `Delegate`. If it can't find one, it returns null.

Now, C# will never let you declare an event with an `add` method that doesn't take a single delegate parameter:

```
public event EventHandler? MyEvent
{
    add { /* value _must_ be of type EventHandler */ }
    // remove goes here 
}
```

As you see above, the `add` method takes a single parameter of the same type as the event's delegate type, named `value`. That's how it always is in C#.

But maybe other languages work differently. Maybe the runtime doesn't care. Either way, from the reflection API's standpoint, anything might go. And hence, it might return null.

If you know which events you're inspecting, and you know they were all declared in C#, then you can assume they're never null.